# Problem with aligning text in div and input

Tags: html, css, text-alignment, font-family

I am trying to vertically align the text in input and `div`, but when it can't be exactly in the middle because of odd number of pixels, it's sometimes closer to top edge, and sometimes to bottom one.

This happens only with some font families, and you can notice that increasing/decreasing line height for `1px` will change position of the text in `div`, but not in input. However, input will start to behave the same as div if line height is greater that `23px`.

Here is the example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pss3zh

I would want for input and `div` to position the text the same way for any `line-height` set.

Comment: did you try `vertical-align: middle;`

Comment: Yes, but it's still not working.

Comment: Did you try with `align-self`?

Comment: Seems fine to me.

Comment: @Nicola `align-self` doesn't solve anything.

Comment: @LppEdd I updated example, check now.